# build.sh return Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v: without any input

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Mac OS X 10.15.3 on MBP.
bash: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release
sorce code hash: da5c5adf7ed11108a571465e737a124139a5f782

I tried to use Autoware Docker environments. I just followed instruction of wiki(https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Generic-x86-Docker)
I wanted to create a Custom Autoware Docker Container. So my case should be `Case 3`.

I just run `./build.sh` in *generic* directory. I got only this response.
`Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:`

I tried several patterns. like

`./build.sh -c off`
Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:

`./build.sh --help`
Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:

Why did I always get this response(`Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:`)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346299/build.sh-return-invalid-parameter:-bc:hi:r:t:v:-without-any-input/) by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-03-12**:
@Kobecow

What does this give?

```
./build.sh --help
```

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
same result.
Got `Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:`

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-03-12**:
There is something wrong when you get the same error for

```
./build.sh --help
```

Check all your steps again or redo again from scracth!

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
I see. But I did more than 2 times following this link https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Generic-x86-Docker

Also I checked all step using `set -x` option.

```
./build.sh --help
+ CUDA=on
+ IMAGE_NAME=autoware/autoware
+ TAG_PREFIX=local
+ ROS_DISTRO=melodic
+ BASE_ONLY=false
+ VERSION=
++ getopt --options bc:hi:r:t:v: --long base-only,cuda:,help,image-name:,ros-distro:,tag-prefix:,version: --name ./build.sh -- --help
+ OPTS=' -- bc:hi:r:t:v: --long base-only,cuda:,help,image-name:,ros-distro:,tag-prefix:,version: --name ./build.sh -- --help'
+ eval set -- ' -- bc:hi:r:t:v: --long base-only,cuda:,help,image-name:,ros-distro:,tag-prefix:,version: --name ./build.sh -- --help'
++ set -- -- bc:hi:r:t:v: --long base-only,cuda:,help,image-name:,ros-distro:,tag-prefix:,version: --name ./build.sh -- --help
+ true
+ case $1 in
+ '[' '!' -z bc:hi:r:t:v: ']'
+ echo 'Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:'
Invalid parameter: bc:hi:r:t:v:
+ exit 1
```

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
This is output when I ran `./build.sh --help`
build.sh contains `set -ex` line 2.

Have you tried same thing on MacOS?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-03-12**:
To guarantee that `bash` is actually the one doing the processing, try running this instead:

`$(which bash) -c "build.sh --help"`

Just FYI - MacOS is not a supported platform for Autoware.

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
$(which bash) -c "build.sh --help"
`/bin/bash: build.sh: command not found`

I think it is wrong way to use `-c` option.
I should run `$(which bash) -c "bash build.sh --help"`.

But I got same result.

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
I think I should you use Ubuntu.
I will use EC2(AWS) for using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Official answer: MacOS is not a supported platform for Autoware.ai (including for building Docker images). For a list of supported platforms, see https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/Source-Build

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kobecow](https://answers.ros.org/users/52364/kobecow/) on 2020-03-12**:
Thank you.
I will use Ubuntu